# How to upload a live photo to the server?

Tags: ios, objective-c, upload, afnetworking-3, phlivephoto

How do I upload Live photos to a server? I am using AFNetworking for the upload of images, videos, and Slow motion videos. The upload of images and videos is very straightforward.

**Upload of Images and Videos**

```
//Physical location i.e. URL for video

 PHVideoRequestOptions *options = [PHVideoRequestOptions new];
        options.networkAccessAllowed = YES;
        [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:asset options:options resultHandler:^(AVAsset *asset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *info) {
            if ([asset isKindOfClass:[AVURLAsset class]]) {
                NSLog(@"%@",((AVURLAsset *)asset).URL);
            }
}];



//Physical location i.e. URL for an image

 [asset requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:nil
                                       completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput *contentEditingInput, NSDictionary *info) {
                                           NSURL *imageURL = contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL;

 }];
```

These URLs are used for the upload of images and video Files.

```
// manager is of class AFHTTPSessionManager initialised with background session.   

NSURLsession *uploadTask=[manager uploadTaskWithRequest:request
                                               fromFile:[NSURL URLWithString:fdi.filePath] 
                                               progress:nil
                                      completionHandler:nil];
```

### Upload of Slow Motion file

Slow motion file is a combination of 2 or more video files. If you try to upload it like a normal video file then it would loose its slow motion feature. To work this out, first we  have to create a slow motion file, then save it on the disk and then upload it.

```
  PHVideoRequestOptions *options = [PHVideoRequestOptions new];
        options.networkAccessAllowed = YES;
        [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:asset options:options resultHandler:^(AVAsset *asset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *info) {
            if(([asset isKindOfClass:[AVComposition class]] && ((AVComposition *)asset).tracks.count == 2)){
                //Added by UD for slow motion videos. See Here: https://overflow.buffer.com/2016/02/29/slow-motion-video-ios/

                //Output URL
                NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString *documentsDirectory = paths.firstObject;
                NSString *myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mergeSlowMoVideo-%d.mov",arc4random() % 1000]];
                NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];

                //Begin slow mo video export
                AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
                exporter.outputURL = url;
                exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
                exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;

                [exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        if (exporter.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted) {
                            NSURL *URL = exporter.outputURL;
                            self.filePath=URL.absoluteString;


                           NSURLsession *uploadTask=[manager uploadTaskWithRequest:request
                                           fromFile:[NSURL URLWithString:self.filePath] 
                                           progress:nil
                                  completionHandler:nil];




                         //Use above method or use the below one.


                            // NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
                            //
                            //// Upload
                            //[self uploadSelectedVideo:video data:videoData];
                        }
                    });
                }];


            } 
        }];
```

**How to upload a Live Photo?**

A Live photo is combination of 2 files, *.jpg and *mov. We can neither upload it like a photo or video nor we can create a new file from the combination of 2 or more files like we did with the slow motion video because we have to send both the files of a live photo to the server.

*It is clear that we have to send both the files to the server. But how to send multiple files in a single request.*

Answer (score 1):

Read a very interesting solution to this problem. It suggests that we do not need to upload both the *jpg and *.mov to the server for live photo. We can only upload the video and create image at the server from the mid point of video.

> The Live Photo begins with the middle of the video - I just read this
>   video, find the middle, save the image.

---

> We can also create a Live Photo from a video as the iPhone 6s does.
>   The 6s captures a short video with the photo and plays the video when
>   the photo is 3D touched. However, by using this method of creating a
>   PHLivePhoto and playing it using the PHLivePhotoView, we can get it to
>   work on any iPhone, such as my regular iPhone 6.

Source: [See Here.](https://realm.io/news/hacking-live-photos-iphone-6s/)

We can get the video URL of a live photo. See [How to get extract video URL from a live photo.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39370406/how-to-extract-image-from-a-live-photo)

**But I am not sure whether this would be good solution for this problem. Can any tell me whether it is a good solution or not.**